# What do the power management tools in Linux do? (acpi, pm-utils, etc...)

Tags: linux, arch-linux, xfce, acpi

I am really really confused about the power management tools available for Linux: I have Arch Linux with XFCE on my laptop.

The guides on the the Arch Linux wiki list

- `acpi`
- `acpid`
- `pm-utils`
- `cpufreq`
- `laptop-mode-tools`

to manage power, suspension, disks and CPU, WiFi, etc.

But I can't understand what the relationships between them are. Apparently they don't require each other (dependencies are listed as optional) but it's not clear to me what this implies: do they work together doing different things or are they alternative to each others or conflict with each other or what?

---

At the moment I only have `pm-utils` (+`upower`) installed. Do I also need `acpi` and/or `acpid`? And what about `laptop-mode-tools`: is this kind of supervisor of all the other tools? If so, should I configure only `laptop-mode-tools` or also each of the other tools separately? How do they interact with `lm-sensors` and `cpufreq`?

In addition to this, there is XFCE Power Manager, which seems to be unrelated to any of the above tools, as it works even if they are not installed. So my question is again, if I install the others will they conflict with XFCE Power Manager? And what about the power management options included in `Xscreensaver`? Do they conflict or do they override the settings in XFCE Power Manager (or `acpi` or `pm-utils`)?

All I want to do really is to have an efficient use of energy:

- be able to go to standby/suspension
- don't have the fan running all the time
- don't overheat/damage the CPU and the hard drive
- turn off WiFi when in standby/suspension
- *et cetera*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

- **acpi** is just a small program that displays basic ACPI information.
- **acpid** is a daemon that handles ACPI events - mostly power button, lid, battery and related stuff. For example, if the power button was pressed, acpid runs `shutdown`. When AC power is connected, *acpid* can run the apropriate `laptop-mode-tools` command. If you use *systemd*, then it replaces most of *acpid*'s functionality.
- **cpufreq** (now obsolete) is a set of tools for adjusting CPU frequency. The core functionality is part of the kernel and accessible through `/sys`, and *cpufreq* commands are just for convenience, but some scripts may require them.
- **cpufreqd** (with the **d**) is an user-space daemon that can be used as a replacement for the default kernel-space governors (powersave, ondemand, performance). It is not necessary – for most uses, the standard governors are enough.
- **cpupower** is a replacement for *cpufreq* – it allows setting CPU frequency settings from command line.
- **laptop-mode-tools** does various system adjustments whenever you plug or unplug AC power to your laptop – for example, disk spin-down times or switching cpufreq governors. It is triggered by *acpid* on AC events, and is inactive the rest of the time.

  (Note: Some of the settings in laptop-mode-tools may actually hurt performance and/or sanity; for example, it disables Ethernet autonegotiation, which IMHO is just silly.)
- **pm-utils** handle the preparations of suspending to memory and/or disk (running pre-suspend hooks, choosing the best method). They are inactive the rest of the time.

  You used to need *pm-utils* to cleanly suspend the machine, but on modern machines, *pm-utils* does very little as it can just tell the kernel to suspend. If you use *systemd*, then it replaces *pm-utils*.
- Additionally, *pm-utils* comes with a **pm-powersave** command that performs most of **the same functions** as *laptop-mode-tools*. *pm-powersave* is triggered by *upower* when you plug/unplug AC power, and performs various adjustments.
- **systemd-logind** has functions for suspending/hibernating, and handles the most common ACPI events (lid switch, power button, etc.) It **replaces** *acpid* and *pm-utils* on most systems.

  (Unlike *pm-utils*, however, *systemd-logind* does not come with any pre-suspend hooks or other workarounds by default, and only uses the default kernel suspend method. It expects driver bugs to be fixed in the drivers.)
- **upower** is an abstraction layer for desktop applications to various power parameters. Programs can use it to check battery status, adjust backlight, or suspend the system without having to care about the specific platform. *upower* also uses PolicyKit to allow various actions (suspend, etc) without giving away full root privileges. It relies on *pm-utils* and *acpid*. GNOME and Xfce require *upower* for their "power management" settings.
- **Xfce Power Manager** controls such parameters as display poweroff time, CPU scaling, LCD brightness, ACPI events... (The function are similar to *acpid* and *laptop-mode-tools*, which both only have one system-wide configuration, while XfPM allows per-user settings.) XfPM only manages the policy, but relies on *upower* for the actual mechanisms. Also, XfPM sends out<sup>[citation needed]</sup> such notifications as "Low battery".

Note: I'm not *entirely* sure what is the relation between XfPM, acpid, laptop-mode-tools, and upower. It seems to me that XfPM replaces most of acpid/l-m-t functions, but not all of them.

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation. Let me see if I understand:
**Xfce Power Manager** is a sort of 'GUI' which relies on upower, which needs pm-utils and also acpid (although acpid is not a dependency but this might be an archlinux issue).
**pm-utils** does only suspend and **laptop-mode-tools** does other adjustments, but they do not conflict because they do different things. However they both need **acpid** to know what is going on. And finally **cpufreq** (and cpufreqd) are probably not necessary because the kernel should take care of that. Is this more or less correct?

Comment: @rsom: XfPM is both a GUI for adjusting the settings, and also a daemon that ensures the settings are applied. Other than that, correct.

Comment: but it does so by passing orders to the other tools (sort of a higher-level daemon)?
Also what about the power management settings in **Xscreensaver**? do they override those in XfPM or vice versa?

Comment: AFAIK, Xscreensaver does not do any power-management on its own - it simply sets the apropriate parameters in the X11 server. (Try `xset q`.) It could be that Xfpm simply manages the same settings, *or* that it doesn't manage the screen at all and lets the screensaver do it. (I'm using GNOME, which has its own program named "GNOME Screensaver", and I don't know whether Xscreensaver is Xfce's default... Reading the source of Xfpm would perhaps give the best answer.)

Comment: I think I understand a lot better now. thanks a bunch.

Comment: Also, yes, Xfpm orders upower to change various settings or to suspend the machine. (I'm not sure, though, if it uses upower for everything or just certain parts.)

Comment: @grawity: Your incorrect in regards to `upower` requiring `acpid`.  It does not require `acpid`, and from what I could understand, it never did. your simplistic explanation removed this confusion, simply install both.  The reality is I installed `upower` and `pm-utils`, yet have all the features `acpid` provides.  The question is why?

Comment: Looks like I just found my answer, I read this statement on a Debian Sid wiki page.  "If you use laptop-mode-utils it depends on acpid, pm-utils has options that can replace laptop-mode-tools by placing scripts in /etc/pm/power.d/"